# JBoss Wildfly display values of attributes in jboss-cli command line mode

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8, application-server, jboss-cli

I would like to see values of different attributes while using the jboss-cli.sh commandline tool in JBoss WildFly 8.1 (I think the version doesn't matter that much)

I know how to write values and I know how to list possible attributes to write to ,but I don't know how to check and see what value is there for example set for the mail-smtp attribute.

So I have the following subsystem in the `standalone.xlm`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
    <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
        <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
    </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

It seems to refer to some "mail-smtp" value. I'd like to know what exactly is that mail-smtp attribute's value it is referring to.

How can I find this value out in `jboss-cli.sh` command line tool?

Comment: Is the value itself not "mail-smtp" of the attribute "smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref"?

Answer (score 1):

You have the read-resource-description operation which will help you get a description of the attribute. If you want to understand the value itself i think you have to use higher version of WildFly and see the capabilities and capabilities ref to 'see' to where it points.
For the value itself now it is an outbound-socket-binding ref so it is under /socket-bindings

Comment: There's also the model reference which shows all the operations https://wildscribe.github.io/. Don't forget tab complete as well :) `/subsystem=mail:<TAB>`